# buttons do not align | CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I tried a lot of stuff and my buttons just won't align no matter how hard I try.

[image: This is the screenshot of what I see on my page:]

This is the screenshot of what I see on my page:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhQIw.png)

They should be all just in the center aligned but it just won't.
idk if I do wrong combinations but I've tried a float: left, text-align: center. it just won't
any help would be appreciated.

BHeader is the parent Header that the buttons are in

```css
.BHeader {
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 98%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: right;
}

.HButtons {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: initial;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div className="BHeader">
    <div className="HButtons">
      <button className="BHeader__Home">Home</button>
      <button className="BHeader__Content">Content</button>
      <button className="BHeader__About">About</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share the entire code. Here we have only the css for one button

Comment: We also need to see the HTML structure in order to provide the best possible help

Comment: the button element is `display: inline-block` when set as `initial` so if they wrap it's because of the container width. I put your code inside a live snippet to better show that your html is not telling the whole story here.

Comment: I think you missed the css "justify-content: center;" fo the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how you're using flexbox. You should use it in `.HButtons` (which is the button's container), not in `.BHeader`.

And there's another error too, because `flex-direction` only supports `row`, `row-reverse`, `column` and  `column-reverse` as values, not `right`: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction

You can do something like that. I changed some lines to make look as you was asking for:

```css
.BHeader {
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 98%;

}
.HButtons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* This line it's not necessary, because 'row' is the default value */
    justify-content: center; /* Put the buttons horizontal centered inside the parent */
    gap: 5%;  /* To separate the buttons between themselves */
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5%; /* Based on the percent you use to separate the buttons, just to add some space between the buttons and the bar */
}

.HButtons button {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="BHeader">
    <div class="HButtons">
      <button class="BHeader__Home">Home</button>
      <button class="BHeader__Content">Content</button>
      <button class="BHeader__About">About</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn-group{
  background-color:coral;
  display:flex; /* to make buttons horizontally align */
  justify-content:center; /* to align buttons horizontally center */
}

button{
  padding: 10px;
  margin:10px;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
}

.btn-group-2{
  background-color:royalblue;
  width: 400px;
  margin:auto; /* to align parent div horizontally center */
  display:flex; /* to make buttons horizontally align */
  justify-content:center; /* to align buttons horizontally center */
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group-2">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Try this example and correct your snippet accordingly.